Does "non-physicalism" as a philosophical position have a scientifically meaningful foundation/explanation?

In ontology and the philosophy of mind, a non-physical entity is an
object that exists outside physical reality. The philosophical schools
of idealism and dualism assert that such entities exist, while
physicalism asserts that they do not.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-physical_entity#:~:text=In%20ontology%20and%20the%20philosophy,asserts%20that%20they%20do%20not.


Nonreductive physicalism (NRP) is the metaphysical thesis that claims
that all the entities of our world constitute an ontological and
causal network that is fundamentally physical and, however, cannot be
reduced to nor fully explained by the laws, properties, and concepts
that the basic physical science can discover and articulate.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236035306_Nonreductive_physicalism_understanding_our_metaphysical_paradigm

What I can read on a subject is too vague for a meaningful scientific foundation/theory.
Simply reducing "non-physicalism" to theism also does not make sense (for me).

Not everything is science.

What is "scientifically meaningful foundation" for a philosophical position? Science does not deal with metaphysics. And "non-physicalism", i.e. anything other than physicalism, is too broad to discuss cogently. It includes idealism, panpsychism, neutral monism, dualism, empiricism, etc. Are you actually asking about nonreductive physicalism (which is still physicalism)?

@Conifold - You are echoing David. If there is no common theory, terminology, or understanding (besides different schools of thought), then there is no philosophy as a science (in the modern understanding of this word).

I think it is in part a lazybones syndrome. Why would you risk making a fool of yourself by researching questions that normal science cannot answer if you can safely write another paper about Aristotle?

There is no common theory, terminology, or understanding of "non-physics" either, simply because it covers too many different subjects. That would be a problem even if philosophy was a science, which it is not. If you do not like the answer fix the question.

@Conifold - I believe in overarching purpose. So I am still searching for a reasonable explanation of the purpose of modern-day philosophy.

The question should clearly either ask about non-physicalism (NP) or non-reductive physicalism (NR-P). Currently it mixes both, and thus makes little sense.

As far as I can tell, neither physicalism nor non-physicalism mean anything at all as ontologies, since nobody is defining "physical" to mean anything sufficiently nailed down to exclude the ghosts of demonic wizard prophets except by specific piecemeal exclusion.

@gs - Isn't it strange that the most critical fundamentals that philosophical views are based on are not nailed down?

Natural sciences describe behavior of nature in abstract models. For a long time, science has tried to reduce e.g. all motion of rigid atoms, objects, cosmological bodies and such using only fundamental laws of nature. This is most prominent and successful in the field of physics.
In other fields of natural science or even social science, trying to explain behaviors of complex systems in terms of causation by fundamental forces of nature often did not work well. In such sciences, instead using non-reductive abstract models gave more useful results.
As an example, consider the behavior of humans leaving a building in panic in case of a fire. Each individual acts out of personal emotions, immediate sensation, thoughts and so on. Yet a model might consider "currents" of humans as if there was a liquid and consider all humans being moved by such currents (as top-down causation). Such models may be the most effective way to reproduce actual human behavior. But this does not metaphysically imply that such humans have no more will and are pulled by invisible strings. It just means trying to model each individuals decision process is so fraught with error and complexity that simplified models with currents wins (until better reductive models could maybe be found).
As such, non-reductive models are quite common in various sciences. However they do not prove non-reducibility metaphysically, because absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. Reductionist models may still be possible, just way too complex to be of use to human scientists.
Thus people in science and philosophy can only have opinions about whether the future will show any undisputable evidence of non-reductive causation or not. So metaphysically non-reductive physicalism remains a thesis for now, whereas physicalism is the minimum consensus about any causality we positively know about and can prove like in science class in highschool.
If there was any hard evidence e.g. in physics that physicalism is insufficient, then immediately all of science would accept some alternative to physicalism. However no such proof currently exists. As such, the alternatives to physicalism are not motivated by science, but are mere philosophic alternatives that cannot simply be disproven by mere absence of evidence.

"However no such proof currently exists." If currently there is no hope for physicalism to answer most fundamental questions about our reality, then you absolutely have to fill the void with some kind of placeholder (God, Simulation Hypothesis, explicit understanding of inability to explain).

There is every hope for physicalism to answer most fundamental questions about our reality. We just aren't there yet. We have answers for much of it, but we are just starting to understand the brain well enough to observe the mind in action. Non-physicalism is an old theory from before we had this much understanding, and looks less and less plausible as we understand more. There is lots of evidence that the brain directly affects the mind; there is no evidence except subjective intuition that the mind might be separate from the brain.

@keshlam - Do you understand how this World came to be? Do you understand how life came to be? Do you really believe that our reality is just a random, chaotic bag of unrelated coincidences?

@TheMatrixEquation-balance:  I have an informed layman's understanding of a lot of the cosmology; call it Scientific American level. Ditto the current understandings of how life arose. Do I understand every last detail? No. Do I understand enough that I am comfortable with saying that our reality is the result of random occurrences as driven by the laws of nature? Yes. I don't demand that you believe this. I do recommend that you make an effort to understand the current theories before declaring you don't believe them.

And note that you are trying to invoke a pile of other questions rather than physicalism. Changing the topic is not the strategy of someone with a strong argument.

If you are younger than 40, then I would agree with you.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In that sense, Physicalism is already that placeholder. The assumption that everything we cannot explain yet also follows laws of physics just like those things we can explain is just that, an assumption. It's no worse a placeholder than saying the tooth fairy created the universe to get those teeth.

@tkruse - "In that sense, Physicalism is already that placeholder." - Except that this is a hush-hush placeholder, because the majority of people would still push BS about reasonable scientific explanations about everything in our reality.

The only thing that changed from the dark ages of the religious zealots is that ignorant theism was replaced with even more ignorant atheism.

Philosophy holds no such opinions, and scientists do not care about philosophy in general. But if it makes you feel better, you can be bitter about anything.
